# SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: IDX10511

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

Looking for some answer. First time using Azure AD for authentication on ASP.Net Core and we have registered the app on azure for both my local and Dev-Server. Its working running on my laptop but after deploying to Dev server and changing the Client ID Value, it keeps giving me this error

*SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: IDX10511: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'System.Text.StringBuilder'.
kid: 'System.String'.
Exceptions caught:
'System.Text.StringBuilder'.
token: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken'.
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(string token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)

Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()*

Thank you in advance.

Danny

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @User [45323833](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/users/7503433/45323833.html) posting your [suggestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/422202/access-token-validating-fails-with-jwtsecuritytoke.html) as an answer to help other community members.

" Solution from **Microsoft**: This problem caused due to your app registration:
May you have  defined a scope from Graph API: `User.Read User.ReadBasic.All Mail.Read`
If a scope will be set from Graph API, the token can just be validated from Graph!
You can see that in `jwt.io.` If the aud is like "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" the token is from Graph.
To solve the problem please follow the below steps :

1. To protect our own custom API, you have to register an application to represent it on Azure AD and obtain an `access_token/id_token` for it.
2. Section - Expose an API: Create a new scope: `name = access_as_user`
3. Section - API permissions: Add a new permission for your registered application and your scope access_as_user
4. Section - Manifest: Change entry "`accessTokenAcceptedVersion`" from null to 2
5. Check the new token from azure with `jwt.io`. If the aud is equal the registered application id the token can be successfully validated."

For more information please refer this GitHub issue  [IDX10511: Signature validation failed. Keys tried:](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/1334) & Microsoft Documentation: [Azure AD authentication with ASP.Net core web application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp)

Comment: Hi Ajay i'm not making API, just MVC with AAD. On my laptop (locahostl:xxxx) it's working just fine but stops working using the Client ID from the registered URL for Dev environment. The only difference between the two is the "Client ID" value based on the registered URL. Am i missing something else?

Comment: Hello @Danny , As you are using MVC with AAD then given Microsoft document in answer will help to implement . And also make sure you have added client id ,tenant id correctly in your web.config file . Also please refer this blog for step by step guide : [Azure AD Authentication For MVC Web Application](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-ad-authentication-for-mvc-web-application/)